# Template for beamer, tufte-latex lecture classroom slides and notes

Tags: beamer, tufte, beamerarticle

After having looked up many questions here regarding the use of `beamerarticle` and `tufte-latex` for consistent lecture notes in both handouts and slides, I have come up with a template for anyone out there interested. I hope it will be both helpful and useful for many of you.

It's available on https://github.com/snitramodranoel/lecture.

Does anyone have any suggestions for improvement? Please, let me know.

Comment: It would be nice to add sample pdf files for others to see what it might look like. But as it's written this question seems off-topic as it's advertisement and not asking for debugging help with a specific MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As for your comment on supposedly advertisement, what is the best way to share the knowledge. I don't mean to misuse Stack Exchange.

Comment: Maybe a community wiki https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts could be created for this sort of thing?